# Setting Default Value BuildForm Hook does not work

Tags: hooks, forms, default-settings

I tried to implement the following hook (in my extension "cividoncamillo"), to set a default Contribution Type, but it does not work...
Any Ideas why not?

```
//does not work
function cividoncamillo_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
 if (($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main')){
   $defaults['financial_type_id'] = '1';
   $form->setDefaults($defaults);
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set defaults values and attributes to membership form fields with PHP](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26910/set-defaults-values-and-attributes-to-membership-form-fields-with-php)