# Set defaults values and attributes to membership form fields with PHP

Tags: webform-civicrm

Its possible to set default values of a membership custom fields through a civiCRM hook? 
I have seen that the values are generated by ajax when membership type is changed but i dont see any hook for this.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to do this with the buildForm hook that is described here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/.
Keep in mind that the custom fields are actually posted on a different form, so I usually first dump the form names to the log with `Civi::log()->debug` so I can check what the name I need is.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, finally, I found the form that works with the custom fields in the memberships: CRM_Custom_Form_CustomDataByType